# Scraping list of items and conbining it in to one property

Tags: python, scrapy

My current spider is parsing only product properties and not `item['title']`.
How do I combine it all together 
Page example:

```html
https://universalmotors.ru/motorcycles/lifan/motorcycle-lifan-lf150-13-2017/
```

My spider:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider as CrawlSpider
from ..items import DistPracticalItem


class SitemapSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sitemap3'
    allowed_domains = ['universalmotors.ru']
    sitemap_urls = ['https://universalmotors.ru/sitemap.xml']
    # sitemap_follow = ['deal']
    # sitemap_rules = [(r'^https?://sz.*deal/[0-8]{1,8}\.html$', 'parse_item')]
    sitemap_rules = [('/motorcycles/', 'parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = DistPracticalItem()
      #  item['name'] = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"good__title")]/text()').extract_first()
        item['title'] = response.css("h1.good__title::text").extract()
     #   prop = response.xpath('normalize-space(//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"])').extract()
        item['price'] = response.css('div.deal-info span.campaign-price').css('::text').extract_first()
     #   item['comments'] = response.css('div.comment div.total').css('::text').extract()
#        return item
     #   for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]'):
        for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]'):
           yield {
                'name': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="label_table"])').extract_first(),
                'value': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="value_table"])').extract_first(),
#                'title': response.css("h1.good__title::text").extract()
            }
```

My goal is to get a list of scraped items that would contain list of properties as follow:

```
Title of the Item 1| Price 1 | Property 1, Property 2, property 3
Title of the Item 2| Price 2 | Property 1, Property 2, property 3
Title of the Item 3| Price 3 | Property 1, Property 2, property 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to yield the complete item you want to scrape, your code only yields the properties, not the title and the price.

I modified your code and it seems to be working as intended. I removed the item include and some comments to make it work on my machine.

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider as CrawlSpider


class SitemapSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sitemap3'
    allowed_domains = ['universalmotors.ru']
    sitemap_urls = ['https://universalmotors.ru/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [('/motorcycles/', 'parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.css("h1.good__title::text").extract_first()
        item['price'] = response.css('div.deal-info span.campaign-price').css('::text').extract_first()
        item['properties'] = list()
        for prop in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]'):
            item['properties'].append(
                {
                    'name': prop.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="label_table"])').extract_first(),
                    'value': prop.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="value_table"])').extract_first(),
                }
            )
        yield item
```

Note that I am gathering all the information inside the `item` variable, which in this case is a `dict` and in yours is a `DistPracticalItem`.

You will end up with the following schema:

```
{
  'title': string,
  'price': string,
  'properties': list of dicts with 'name' and 'value' as strings
}
```

Hope I was clear.

Comment: Luiz, greatly appreciate your help! It worked. The only drawback is that when I export to CSV I get extra symbols around properties as such `Мотоцикл LIFAN LF150-13 (2017),,"[{'name': 'Рабочий объем (см.куб.)', 'value': '149.4'}, {'name': 'Подача топлива', 'value': 'карбюратор'}]"` Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: What symbols are you referring to? The quotes (")? Since properties is a list scrapy tries to export it as a string and put quotes on it, try to do `item['properties'] = str(item['properties'])` before the `yield`. I am not sure how to avoid this without testing.